# How do I access the parent element within a Backbone view?

Tags: backbone.js

In Backbone model views, it seems `$(this.el).parent()` doesn't work.  What is the best way to select the parent element from within a view?

I am setting el by using `tagName:  "li"` for the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Backbone assigns an empty `div` to your view and you can't access its parent, until it's been placed in the DOM through your render function.

You can use your approach of `$(this.el).parent()` if you are allowing Backbone to assign the default empty `div`. You can use the `this.el.parent()` if you are assigning `el` yourself in the constructor to a jQuery object.

Comment: I am using the tagName property to set the tag to `li`.  But it was an issue of when it was placed in the DOM.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What are you setting this.el to?  If you're already setting it to a jquery element, for example:

```
this.el = $('#content');
```

then you don't need to wrap it again. Try changing what you have to:

```
this.el.parent()
```

Comment: this overrides the backbone view holder with whatever you find in the DOM with such ID

Comment: No, it doesn't.  That first code snippet was just an example of how the content for the view may be getting set.  If you'll read the actual suggested answer you'll see where I suggest changing what they have to this.el.parent().  Additionally, if you look at the accepted answer by the user you'll see that it makes the exact same suggestion.  In the future, please read the entire post before down voting an almost 2 year old question that actually contains the correct answer.