# Parent element for backbone view?

Tags: backbone.js

How set Parent element for backbone view  ?

```
var TodosView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'p', // required, but defaults to 'div' if not set
className: 'container', // optional, you can assign multiple classes to
// this property like so: 'container homepage'
id: 'todos', // optional

initialize: function(){

 // debugger
  this.$el.html("bamboo4a")
  $("body").append(this.$el);
}
});
var todosView = new TodosView();
```

I do not want to write  $("body").append

Comment: I think this question has already been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982516/how-do-i-access-the-parent-element-within-a-backbone-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the main view you can set the view element when creating the view object by passing the options to its constructor (namely the option `el`).

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: '<p>Hello World!</p>',
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template);
    }
});

new MyView({
    el: 'body' // or el: '#content' and so on
}).render();
```

**[Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor)**

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/dymg1kq3/)**

**[Demo with more detailed example of the application](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/gaptv72a/)**